# Selenium - Firefox compatibility issue , Error ("Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 ....")

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver-2.42.2 and Firefox 29.1 with java as programming language.

Previously I was using Firefox 33.1, which resulted in error -

`org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
e addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible...`

I downgraded the firefox version to 29.1. At first it worked but now, it is again showing the same error. Can anyone suggest another solution than changing the versions.

Comment: The issue says about some addon.Can you try uninstalling that addon and try again.Typically you should use a basic firefox profile without these addons installed.

Comment: If you're receiving same error (Firefox 33.1); Firefox updates itself automatically. You need disable auto update lines from about:config. Then install older version of Firefox.